# WPF - Display single entity with a data template

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I Have a data template that i use in items control,  i wanna know if its possible some how to use it(the template) on single item display without the items control?

if not whats the best way to do it...?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can probably do something like this

```
**<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" DataType="{x:Type MyType}">**
    ...
**</DataTemplate>**
...
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" /> <!-- Single instance use -->
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" /> <!-- Multiple instance use -->
```

Comment: ContentControl Template property expects a ControlTemplate, not a DataTemplate

Comment: ok.. kewl.. fixed my answer as well.. +1 for your quick edit :)